# Some questions about the function $xe^{-x}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to prove that $xe^{-x}$ is bounded by some constant for all the $x \in [0, \infty)$. So I take derivative of this guy, and found that on $x \in [0, \infty)$, its derivative is positive from $[0, 1)$, $0$ at $x=1$, and negative from (1, in infinity). So  $xe^{-x}$ achieves its maximum in $[0, \infty)$ at $x=1$, which is $1/e$. However, to prove that it's bounded by $1/e$, I need to prove that as $x$ goes to infinity, $xe^{-x}$ converges to $0$. Because otherwise, if it went to some value below $(-1/e)$, $xe^{-x}$ would not be bounded by $1/e$. How can I prove that $xe^{-x}$ converges to $0$? I mean, as $x$ goes to infinity, $e^{-x}$ converges to zero, but at the same time, x diverges to infinity. How can I formally prove that the product term converges to $0$? Do I need to use the epsilon definition of convergence to prove it?

Could you just show me the formal proof of $xe^{-x}$ converges to $0$? Or is there's any other way to approach this question? My professor suggested that I should use the power series for $e^{-x}$...?

Your help is greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!

I hope you enjoy your Saturday!

Comment: Do you know Taylor series, l'Hospital's rule, derivatives...?

Comment: yes...for sure but...

Comment: How can $xe^{-x}$ goes below $-\frac1e$ for $x\ge0$?

Comment: I know this for sure. But this is a proof class so I need to write the proof...

Comment: ok so i just use l'Hospital's rule, right?

Comment: @mflowww : to answer the question you were given, you do _not_ need to show $xe^{-x} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. All you need to show is that it $xe^{-x}>0$ for $x \geq 1$ (obvious) and  us the fact that $xe^{-x}$ is a decreasing function of $x$ for $x \geq 1$ (which you already did).

Comment: @mflowww : it is odd that the professor suggested that you do something that is unnecessary for solving the problem.  It is nice to be able to prove $xe^{-x} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$, but sometimes in mathematics it is important to know exactly what is necessary to do to solve a problem, because if you try something too hard, you may not be able to do it.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**l'Hospital's Rule** :

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac x{e^x}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{e^x}=0$$

**Taylor Series:**

$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}2+\ldots\implies\frac x{e^x}=\frac1{\frac1x+1+\frac x2+\ldots}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}0$$

Do try to justify each step above.